# Text overflow issue on mobile careers site

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, mobile-web

I was looking at the mobile careers site and noticed some of the first text wasn't wrapping correctly.

This is one on a nexus 5, android 4.4 with chrome browser.

[image]

Comment: Could you give me the URL that you're accessing here?

Comment: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/subscribe

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a fixed width problem. Patched it up and it should be working with our next production build in an hour or so.